# Javascript input onkeypress function do not work

Tags: javascript, onkeypress

I put the script in head tags

```
function check(e, regexp) {
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Gecko') != -1) {
        charCode = e.which;
    } else {
        charCode = e.keyCode;
    }
    if(charCode > 31) {
        znak = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        return regexp.test(znak);
    }
}
```

When I use this function in input

```
<input id='pole2' name=nip style='WIDTH: 300px;' onkeypress='return check(event, /[0-9-]/i);'>
```

it works great with HTML. 
But when I create in javascript input with id='odbiorca' and if I try to use onkeypress with the same code

```
document.getElementById("odbiorca").onkeypress = function() {myfunction()};
function myFunction(){
    return check(event, /[0-9- ]/i);
}
```

It does not want to work. What is wrong?

Comment: "It does not work" is not a proper problem description. How do you know it does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of the script should be written like this:

```
document.getElementById("odbiorca").onkeypress = function(event) {return check(event, /[0-9- ]/i);}
```

As you see the typo was not a main problem. Keep this solution for others.
Thanks to Merijn for suggestion with browser console.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you mispelled myFunction:

```
document.getElementById("odbiorca").onkeypress = function() {myfunction()};

function myFunction(){
    return check(event, /[0-9- ]/i);
}
```

myFunction is with a capital F but you call it with a small f (myfunction instead of myFunction) beside that it should work!

EDIT: try to check your browser console first next time. You could have seen the very clear error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined
at HTMLInputElement.document.getElementById.onkeypress
```

Comment: If it is a typo, comment and flag/vote2close.  Don't answer questions that won't help anyone else.